# How to force a git branch to be ahead of master branch when actually it is behind?

Tags: git

How can I make my develop branch ahead of master branch?

What happened was:

1. There is no git repo
2. I found some old code, i.e. version 1.0
3. I started working on it and changed some behavior, i.e. version 1.1
4. I decided that I should create a git repo before things get messy, and I did
5. I pushed version 1.1 to the repo as origin/master as the initial commit
6. But what I really wanted was to create a tag for version 1.0,
7. So I also created origin/develop with version 1.1
8. Then I checked out origin/master, deleted my changes, commited and tagged it version 1.0 again.
9. I git push the tag and changes to master
10. Now my master is ahead of develop
11. But actually I want develop to be ahead of master

I tried to git pull and rebase, but both changed my develop version 1.1 into master version 1.0.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all --branches` in your local repository should show you something like:

```
x commit for 1.0 (HEAD, master, origin/master)
|
x commit for 1.1 (develop, origin/develop)
```

You can therefore reset your `develop` branch to `master`, and cherry-pick your old `develop` commit, *on top of* `master`.

```
git switch -C develop master
git cherry-pick origin/develop
git push -f -u origin develop
```

(assuming here there was only only commit on `develop`)

The new log should show `develop` ahead of `master` now:

```
x commit for 1.1 (HEAD, develop, origin/develop)
|
x commit for 1.0 (master, origin/master)
```